# How to group some Edits and Labels with rounded background colors in Android

Tags: android, background, tableview

in my app, I generate dynamically dialogs with labels, edits, checkboxes etc.

The layout is based on a TableView, which lays on a ScrollView and it's pretty simpel, since there are only 1 or 2 objects in each TableRow.

Now I have to group some of these TableRows with a specific color and rounded corners.
Until now, I don't use any concrete coordinates, but let Android do the stuff. I just read my incoming data and create as many rows as needed.

Has anyone a good idea, how this could be realized?
Can I read the actual coordinates during the rendering process in Android so hat I can create the background image and lay it underneath the dialog?

Any ideas are welcome ;-)

Comment: why do you need coordinates...?? For grouping you can apply backgrounds,color,etc when you are dynamically generating them and adding them to the layout...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define your own styles and apply them to the items.